# DTO Mapping using AutoMapper

Tags: c#, .net, linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-entities

I have 3 tables tableA, tableB and tableC where tableB has a foreign key from tableA 
and tableC has a foreign key from tableB and similarly with tableD.

I have a linq query which I am getting data as 
:

```
var temp  = await dbContext.tableA.Include(p=>p.tableB.Select(q=>q.tableC).Select(s=>s.tableD)).ToListAsync();
```

I am getting proper data here.But when I map this to DTO like this :

```
{
List<DTOtableA> dtotest = new List<DTOTableA>();
//From DB
var list = _repo.GetData();

dtotest = list.Select(p=>Mapper.Map(p,new DTOTableA())).ToList();
}
```

Here only data of tableA is getting populated in dtoTest even though DTOTableA has reference to DTOTableB in its class and also DTOTableB has reference to DTOTableC
.

Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think,you don't need mapper. You can use like that:

List< DTOtableA > dtotest  = await dbContext.tableA.Include(p=>p.tableB.Select(q=>q.tableC).Select(s=>s.tableD)).ToListAsync();

dtotest[0].tableB.attributeOfTableB